# Finding a three digit number, with properties of a geometric progression such that by subtracting 400 forms an arithmetic progression number

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find a three digit number if its digits form a geometric progression and the digits of the number which is smaller by 400 forms an arithmetic progression.

Comment: What are you thoughts about this question ? What did you try ?

There aren't many 3 digit numbers with digits that form a geometric progression.

Comment: i tried finding relations b/w a,d,r but ended up with two equations only . i got a third by multiplying hundredth term by100 , tenth term by 10 but i again got same related . i have 2 equations and 3 variables

Comment: There's no need to use equations, the digits have to form a GP in some configuration but not necessarily when they're making up the number.

Comment: the answer is 931

Comment: GP-a/r,a,ar
AP-a-d,a,a+d

Comment: 124 is also an answer.

Comment: a/r=a-d+4
a=ar-rd+4r

ar=a+d

so, r=d/d-4
hence a=d^2-4d/4

Comment: how can 124 be an answer?? 124-400 will be a negative no.

Comment: Put $ (dollar signs) around the math to make it more readable. The question asks for a number with AP digits, it doesn't matter if it's negative or not. The order doesn't matter also.

Comment: ok . ignore the negative answer . i just want to get 931 as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Hint: check 3 digit numbers with $x^0$ as one of the digits and $1\le x\le 9$.

Edit:

For example:

$x^0=a, x^1=b, x^2=c$

Such that $a,b,c$ are digits, and try subtracting 400 from numbers like so:

$abc\\ cba\\ bca\\...$

Comment: sorry but i didn't get your point

Comment: @arpit the point is it can be solved by trial and error by trying all the possible combinations, only $x=2$ or $x=3$ will form a GP 3 digit number so there are 12 combinations ($2\cdot 3!$), it's not a lot to go through.

Comment: I found a better way
GP- a,ar,ar^2
AP- a-4,ar,ar^2
2ar=a-4+ar^2
(r-1)^2=4/a
since r is real no. , a must be a perfect square(5<a<9)
so only possible value is a=9
next we get (r-1)= +/- 2/3
but we take (r-1)=-2/3
so , r=1/3
and the no. is 931

Comment: @arpit It's hard to read without the latex. Your assumption on the GP is wrong I think, what is r? The GP is $x^0, x^1, x^2,..$ You also say that $x<9$, then state that it has to be $x=9$. Contradiction.

Comment: You're also wrong about the perfect square: $6^2=36$ a two digit number. In fact any number larger than 3 will be larger than 9 when squared i.e a two digit number.